# Updating forgetting factor in un-normalized lattice recursive least squares adaptive filter

Tags: adaptive-filters

The algorithms given for [un-normalized LRLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_least_squares_filter#Lattice_recursive_least_squares_filter_(LRLS)) and [normalized LRLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_least_squares_filter#Normalized_lattice_recursive_least_squares_filter_(NLRLS)) filters on Wikipedia are transcribed from Adaptive Filtering Algorithms and Practical Implementation by Paulo S. R. Diniz. In reading the book, I noticed the author has this to say of the forgetting factor λ.

> Another interesting feature of the normalized lattice algorithm is that the forgetting factor λ does not appear in the internal updating equations; it appears only in the calculation of the energy of the input and reference signals. This property may be advantageous from the computational point of view in situations where there is a
>   need to vary the value of λ.

I do not understand whether the author is saying that updating the factor is impossible with the un-normalized form, or computationally expensive. Nor do I understand what prevents one from updating the factor over time when using the un-normalized form. To me, it looks simple to parameterize the forgetting factor in terms of k for either algorithm. Could someone help me shed light on precisely what is meant here and why it is true?

Comment: Hi: I don't know the answer to your question but I'm interested in this field of adaptive filtering.  ( I'm familar with kalman filter and background is econometrics/stat time-series ). Is this book good for an introduction. I have some experience with numerical optimization and time series methods so I'm interested in what is meant by "adaptive".  Thanks and I'm sorry that I can't help you with your question.

Comment: The book is extremely math heavy and goes very in-depth. It's a good comprehensive text, but I think if you want an intro to the subject you're better off with a chapter from a signal processing textbook. I don't really have a favorite to recommend; the best intro I got was a professor's slide set + lecture.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that. You make a good point. I'm sorry that no one has responded. If I could respond with something intelligent, I would. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with this topic.